# What am I supposed to do about pending messages on a decommissioned cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra

I am referring official documentation at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRemoveNode.html for removing a node from a cassandra cluster.

After the node is decommissioned 'nodetool netstats' gives:

```
Mode: DECOMMISSIONED
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 0
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         4              0         0
Small messages                  n/a         4             21         0
Gossip messages                 n/a         0         132998         0
```

By looking at value of 'Mode', I feel that the node is successfully decommissioned/ removed. But I start doubting when I see there are 'Pending' messages.

I could not find any info about how can I interpret this info and what am I supposed to do?
Is the node really removed? Do I need to ensure that there are no pending messages? How can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **nodetool status** on other nodes doesn't showing removed server, desregard the pending messages, there's not much you can do after the node is removed from the cluster.

Review **system.log**, and see if the node completed decommission successfully and if there were any errors, add them to question.

Comment: On decommissioned nodes, the directory for logs i.e. "/var/log/cassandra/" is no longer available. I am using  c* 3.7. And by the way, nodetool status on other nodes doesn't show the decommissioned nodes. So I think and as you are suggesting decommissioning is successful and i can disregard the decommissioned nodes.

Comment: Yes, decommission is successful